# How to make Plesk Real-Time Replication form one plesk to another

Tags: plesk

I have 3 Plesk server

1. Server A (Production)
2. Server B (Production)
3. Server C (For Replication)

Now I want to make replication (Real-Time) from Server A, Server B to Server C,
How can I make Replica?

Note: Important Is MySQL Replica (Real-Time) from Server A, Server B to Server C.

I haven't found any documentation regarding that

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the new HA feature? It's probably what you are seeking:
https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/install-plesk-high-availability-cluster/